# I'm trying to change the flags on my files I copied before stating fresh with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, lubuntu, 22.04, files

I made a copy of my files on a USB hard drive before starting fresh with Ubuntu 22.04. How do I change the ownership of the directories on the USB hard drive, file and sub-directories? I just want to put them on the new installation so I can edit then. I've tried the chown command and can't get the syntax correct. I've looked at as many posts as I can find and I'm getting lost in all of the information.

This is my /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device;this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /  ext4  errors=remount-ro 0  1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=819C-B893  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none  swap  sw  0  0
```

Comment: Did you then copy to NTFS which does not support Linux ownership & permissions? If so you have to copy back to your data partition or /home partition or folder & change permissions & ownership then. Be careful not to change any system ownership or permissions which can damage system.

Comment: I took a new Seagate 5Tb  USB drive and with Gparted removed all partitions and created another one with a file system of ext4.

Comment: Did you use gpt. which is required for any drive over 2TB, over old MBR(msdos) partitioning. You then should be able to mount & set ownership & permissions. If removable, you can add to fstab, but need extra parameters since removable drive, like autofs or systemd-automount. But still have do settings. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types

Comment: I'm not sure you'll need to change permissions (*though it may depend on how you copied the files initially or details not provided*). I'm using a newish PC installed last week (Lubuntu) as my old PC died; I just copied my files onto the fresh install where no `chown` was required.  If your USB drive uses a format that can't store ownership data (as per oldfred's query) you can't change ownership there, but can easily do so once on your local hdd/ssd which is what I'd suggest doing.

Comment: You were correct. Once I moved the files off the drive I saved them to and on my new install I have read/write and delete access. thank you all for your help.